# How can I round Time epoch to previous midnight

Tags: c++, epoch

Let's say I have :
time in msec = 1655205146419  , which is generated using :

```
auto msec = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Tuesday, June 14, 2022 11:12:26.419 AM

And I want to round it up to the previous midnight :

Tuesday, June 14, 2022 00:00:00.00 AM

any ideas how ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/floor with a duration https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration of 1 day:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
 
int main()
{
    using Day = std::chrono::days;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::floor<Day>(start).time_since_epoch()).count() << "\n";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z89nr4Mo3

increased readability when storing the days in a variable:

```
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto days = std::chrono::floor<Day>(start).time_since_epoch();
std::cout << duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(days) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that this requires a change in the conditions since OP has the time in milliseconds since the epoch - but staying within the `chrono` domain is preferable so changing the conditions may be a good thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right, I skipped this part of the question unintentionally. I upvoted your answer because it gives an answer to that question. I also think that converting the number back to a `time_point` object is rather easy and the main question was how to `floor` it to midnight.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say I have : time in msec = 1655205146419

I'd try to stay within the `chrono` domain as much as it is possible, but if you are forced to use *milliseconds since the epoch* as an input value:

```cpp
auto midnight_tp = system_clock::time_point(milliseconds(msec)) - 
                       milliseconds(msec) % days(1);
// or
auto midnight_tp = floor<days>(system_clock::time_point(milliseconds(msec)));
```

Getting to the unitless *milliseconds since the epoch* again is just a repetition what you've already done earlier:

```cpp
auto midnight_msec =
    duration_cast<milliseconds>(midnight_tp.time_since_epoch()).count();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r8zMTzT67)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, not as pretty, but you can play a bit with [`std::tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) and get answers that you wish.

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::time_t now = time(0);
    std::tm tstruct;

    char current_time[20];
    char last_midnight[20];
    tstruct = *std::localtime(&now);
    std::strftime(current_time, sizeof(current_time), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    tstruct.tm_hour = 00;
    tstruct.tm_min = 00;
    tstruct.tm_sec = 00;
    std::strftime(last_midnight, sizeof(last_midnight), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    std::cout << "current_time: " << current_time << std::endl;
    std::cout << "last_midnight: " << last_midnight << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Output results](https://godbolt.org/z/MdbGnr1bT)

Comment: It does however not answer how to get from _milliseconds since the epoch_ to the point where you can truncate it down to midnight.